# How to create a MemoryStream for iCal files in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, icalendar, memorystream

I am trying to create an ICS calendar file using memorystream (in ASP.NET 4.0) as under:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public MemoryStream GetMemoryStream()
{
    iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
    Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();

    // Set information about the event
    evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(SomeStartTime);
    evt.End = new iCalDateTime(SomeEndTime);
    evt.Location = SomeLocation;
    evt.Description = SomeDescription;
    evt.Summary = SomeSummary;

    iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer(iCal);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(iCal, ms, Encoding.UTF8);
    return ms;
}
```

I guess I am missing something. Can anyone help me to create correct `MemoryStream` object out of it ?

**Note :** I need that `MemorySteam` object to create an `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` for `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see the MemoryStream is being disposed by the Serializer.
I got around it by converting the calendar to a string then converting the string to a MemoryStream

```
using System.IO;
using System;

public MemoryStream GetMemoryStream()
{
    iCalendar iCal = new iCalendar();
    Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();

    // Set information about the event
    evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(SomeStartTime);
    evt.End = new iCalDateTime(SomeEndTime);
    evt.Location = SomeLocation;
    evt.Description = SomeDescription;
    evt.Summary = SomeSummary;

    iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer(iCal);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    //serializer.Serialize(iCal, ms, Encoding.UTF8);
    var ics = serializer.SerializeToString(iCal);
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ics);
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return ms;
}
```